# cin stuck reading the same value over and over

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to solve the following problem: https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3693

Here's my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <limits>

typedef unsigned int ui;

int main(){
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(0);

    ui m,n;
    std::cin >> m >> n;
    while(m){
        std::vector<int> objects(n);
        for(auto i = 0u; i < n; i++){
            std::cin >> objects[i];
        }

        //memoizacion
        std::map<std::pair<ui, ui>, ui> mem;

        std::function<ui(std::pair<ui, ui>)> question = [&](std::pair<ui, ui> set) -> ui {
            if(!mem.count(set)){
                int inSet = 0;
                for(auto i = 0u; i < n; i++){
                    if(((objects[i] & set.first) == set.first) and (((~objects[i]) & set.second) == set.second))
                        inSet++;
                }
                if(inSet <= 1) mem.insert(std::pair<std::pair<ui, ui>, ui>(set, 0));
                else {
                    ui min = std::numeric_limits<ui>::max();
                    for(auto k = 1u, i = 0u; i < m; i++, k <<= 1){
                        if(!(k & set.first) and !(k & set.second)){
                            ui candidate = std::max(question(std::pair<ui,ui>(set.first | k, set.second)),
                                                    question(std::pair<ui, ui>(set.first, set.second | k)));
                            min = min < candidate ? min : candidate;
                        }
                    }
                    mem.insert(std::pair<std::pair<ui, ui>, ui>(set, min + 1));
                }
            }
            return mem.at(set);
        };

        std::cout << question(std::pair<ui, ui>(0,0)) << "\n";

        std::cin >> m >> n;
    }
}
```

When I run this code using the example input (on the pdf detailing the problem in the link), my code solves the first two cases, then enters an infinite loop in the third case

When I went check it out with a debugger, I notices that the line

```
std::cin >> m >> n;
```

is the one causing an error. After reading the third case, when it tries to read again it does nothing. m and n are unchanged once it hits the m = 11, n = 16 case. Like it gets called over and over again (because the loop's condition to end is for m to be 0), but instead of reading the next input it's just stuck there, repeating the same values for m and n

I'm honestly completely lost. I have zero idea what's going on here and I've been hitting my head against a wall trying to solve this for the past hour

Comment: `while (std::cin >> m >> n) { ... }` is the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that if you do `std::cin >> m >> n;` and there's nothing for `cin` to read, `m` will be set to `0`. But actually, let's take a look at what `operator>>` does:

[operator>>(std::basic_istream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

```cpp
basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned int& value ); (2)
```

> 1-11) Extracts a value potentially skipping preceding whitespace. The value is stored to a given reference `value`.
>
> This function behaves as a [FormattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, extracts a value by calling `std::num_get::get()`.

And what does a [FormattedInputFunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction) do if it fails to read?

> A FormattedInputFunction is a stream input function that performs the following:
>
> - Constructs an object of type basic_istream::sentry with automatic storage duration and with the noskipws argument set to false, which performs the following
>
>   - if `eofbit` or `badbit` are set on the input stream, sets the `failbit` as well, and if exceptions on `failbit` are enabled in this input stream's exception mask (`(exceptions() & failbit) != 0`), throws `ios_base::failure`.
>   - flushes the `tie()`'d output stream, if applicable
>   - if `ios_base::skipws` flag is set on this input stream, extracts and discards characters from the input stream until one of the following becomes true:
>
>     - the next available character on the input stream is not a whitespace character, as tested by the `std::ctype` facet of the locale currently imbued in this input stream. The non-whitespace character is not extracted.
>     - the end of the stream is reached, in which case `failbit` and `eofbit` are set and if the stream is on for exceptions on one of these bits, `ios_base::failure` is thrown.
> - Checks the status of the sentry by calling `sentry::operator bool()`, which is equivalent to `basic_ios::good`.
> - If the sentry returned `false` or sentry's constructor threw an exception, **no input takes place**

Emphasis added. If `std::cin >> m` doesn't have anything to read, it leaves `m` alone. So after a failed read `m` is still `11`, not `0`, so `while(m)` is still `true`.

---

A note regarding the above: There *are* circumstances where a failed read `std::cin >> m` would result in `m` being set to `0`. If there actually is data available to read in the stream, but this data cannot be converted into an integer in the `std::num_get::get()` step:

[std::num_get::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get):

> If the conversion function fails to convert the entire field, the value `​0`​ is stored in `v`.

---

The recommended approach is to directly check whether the read itself was successful. So, instead of `std::cin >> m >> n;` followed by checking the value of `m`, you would write the loop as

```cpp
while(std::cin >> m >> n)
{
  // Do stuff...
}
```

This relies on the fact that `std::istream` has an [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that indicates whether the most recent stream operations succeeded or not. This way, all failures to read from `cin` are treated uniformly.